# How can I pass a query param from my service on the front end to my server?

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm trying to get the user data back from my database, but I can't seem to figure out how to send a query param to my server in order to do such a thing. My angular front end is running on a different port than my server (not sure that matters) but I can't figure it out.

I've tried using http.get to call the backend, but that doesn't seem to work.

This is the code in my auth.service:

```
reload() {
    this.http.get('/user', {params: {userId: 'test'}});
}
```

This is the code on my server

```
app.get("/user/?userId", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('hello  2ddsaczczxczxC')
    console.log(req);
})
```

My console logs aren't logging anything so it's clearly not reaching the backend at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the change required for accessing any as such request parameters. Update your rest end point to

```
/user/:userid

app.get("/user/:userId", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('hello  2ddsaczczxczxC')
  console.log(req.params);
})
```

Then access the query using either by request.params or req.query please check the documentation of expressjs as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
app.get("/user/:userId", (req, res, next) => {
   console.log();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass query parameter by doing this

```
 reload() {
    this.http.get('/user', {queryParams: {userId: 'test'}});
}
```